# Adding top contributed repositories

Tags: discussion, feature-request, developer-story

Currently, it looks like the "open source" option in Developer Story suggests that the "open source" you add was *created by you*. Can you please add an option to add repositories you *contributed* to but aren't yours? Something like GitHub's pinned repositories. I think it's something that both developers and companies looking at Developer Stories can benefit from

Comment: I don't think there should be two different categories. Perhaps a change in wording is sufficient?

Comment: So maybe just a checkbox to check to mark as a repository you just contribute to?  They should have something to differentiate between them I think

Comment: Why not just state in the description what you think your role was/is? A simple sentence like "I'm the owner / the creator / one of the maintainers / a major contributor / a regular contributor / an occasional contributor / a one-time contributor (but included major feature xyz) for that package/repository/whatever".

Comment: Because sometimes you contribute code to a big project but you don't have a role in it. And you still get some value from showing those contributions in a Developer Story. It's not a timeline major event like writing your own repository. But it's worth mentioning. Having a repository you created shown in the same way as a repository you contributed a few pull requests to might make the difference unclear

Comment: Agree... It would be nice to see *repositories you contribute to* be available in the 'import from github' option. Perhaps there could also be a distinction when you are a *collaborator* on the repository or member of the owning organization, as opposed to just someone who has made a contribution at some point in time.